# File not updating after it is closed

Tags: python, django, file, django-forms

I have asked a few questions here related to a Django project I am working on which displays the contents of a file in a form, and you can edit the file with the form, when you submit it the project writes to the file and the changes are automatically reflected.

So I have gotten the project to display the contents of a calendar text file in the form, and I have been able to get the form content into my Python script for manipulation. The issue I am having is writing that content to a file, because for some reason, the changes never commit themselves until after I restart the server (this is not ideal, as this should be able to run continuously).

I suspect this has something to do with the file still remaining open for some reason after it is "closed". I attempted to fix that by creating functions for all read and write actions (that close the file as well) so I can call them every time I need to read/write. The issue still persists. Is there something I am doing incorrectly here? Is the file still open somewhere I cannot find? Resources below.

**Link to project:** https://repl.it/@xMikee/Calendar (*calendar is just a template for the time being*)

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import FileForm
import sys

f = open('calendar.txt', "r")
file_content = f.read()
f.close()
if f.closed:
  print("CLOSED FILE from read views")

def writeFile(content, file):
  f = open(file, "w")
  f.write(content)
  f.close()
  if f.closed:
    print("CLOSED FILE from write views")

def home(request):
  return render(request, 'main/index.html',{'file_content':file_content})

def form_get(request):
  print('got form')
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print("OK")
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = FileForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
      print("OK")
      cd = form.cleaned_data['form']
      writeFile(cd, 'calendar.txt')
  else:
    print('NOT OK')
    form = FileForm()
  return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': form})

def thanks(request):
  # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print("OK")
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = FileForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
      print("OK")
      cd = form.cleaned_data['form']
      print(cd)
      f = open('calendar.txt', 'r+')
      f.write(cd)
      f.close()
  else:
    print('NO POST')
    form = FileForm()
  return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
global cd

f = open('calendar.txt', "r")
file_content = f.read()
f.close()
if f.closed:
  print("CLOSED FILE from read views")

class FileForm(forms.Form):
  form = forms.CharField(label='',initial=file_content,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'width':"100%", 'cols' : "102", 'rows': "40", }))
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1 style='text-align:center'>Welcome to the calendar!</h1>
  <div style='text-align:center'>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div style='margin: 0 auto'>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
  <p>{{cd}}</p>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```